# How can I simulate strings.xml using Swift

Tags: swift, string, api, endpoint

I want to use a Struct to set my endpoints.

The problem is when some endpoint needs parameters, I mean, this is how it looks on code:

**on Strings.XML (Android)**

```
   <string name="get_users">MyAPI/GetUsers</string>
    <string name="get_user_by_id">MyAPI/GetUser/%d</string>
```

**on Swift**

```
import Foundation
struct Endpoints {
    static let get_users = "MyAPI/GetUsers"
    static let get_user_by_id = "MyAPI/GetUser/????"
}
```

How can I make the second one on Swift?

Thank you so much for your attention

Comment: You can use `String(format:)` and keep the place holder. You can also check this https://www.swiftbysundell.com/clips/4/ (enum with associated value for instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use case, I'd use an enum, like so:

```
enum Endpoints {
    case get_users
    case get_user_by_id(String)

    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .get_users:
            return "MyAPI/GetUsers"
        case .get_user_by_id(let id):
            return "MyAPI/GetUser/\(id)"
        }
    }
}
```

The following

```
print(Endpoints.get_users.path)
print(Endpoints.get_user_by_id("foo").path)
```

prints

```
MyAPI/GetUsers
MyAPI/GetUser/foo
```